# New column based on rows from specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of data like on image.
I need to get sequences which **Type** are "secstr", fill it to new column next to column **Sequence** which have same **PDB_ID** number and **Chain**. At the end I want to delete rows with "secstr" sequences.

So far I have something like that:

```
["Secstr"] = sequences.Sequence[
    (sequences['PDB_ID'] == sequences['PDB_ID']) & 
    (sequences['Chain'] == sequences['Chain']) & 
    (sequences['Type'] == 'secstr')]
```

[Image with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMVjF.png)

The data I need should look like this:

```
    PDB_ID  Chain          Sequence                  Secstr
0   101M     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHH  HHHHGGHH HHHH
1   102L     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA    HHHH  HHHHHHHGGHH   HH
2   102M     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA    HHHHHHHHHGGHH HHH     
3   103L     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHHH HHHHHH HHGGH 
4   103L     B       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHHH HHHHHH HHHHH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the original DF and the DF extracted by 'secstr' to remove unnecessary columns. Does this meet the intent of the question?

```
# Splitting the DF by 'Type'
df2 = df[df['Type'] == 'secstr']
df2.set_index(['PDB_ID','Chain'], inplace=True)
# Extract and divide 'Type' except 'secstr' ('sequence' extraction)
df = df[~(df['Type'] == 'secstr')]
df.set_index(['PDB_ID','Chain'], inplace=True)

# Combining DF and DF2 (in the column direction)
new_df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Renaming a column
new_cols = ['PDB_ID', 'Chain', 'Type', 'Sequence', 'Type1', 'Secstr']
new_df.columns = new_cols

# Deleting unnecessary columns
new_df.drop(columns=new_df.columns[[2,4]], inplace=True)

    new_df
    PDB_ID  Chain   Sequence    Secstr
0   101M    A   HJGDSDDLKEIEWUSKDSK OLKDSJDJFYEUKIBK
1   102L    A   HJGDSDDLKEIEWUSKDSK OLKDSJDJFYEUKIBK
2   102M    A   HJGDSDDLKEIEWUSKDSK OLKDSJDJFYEUKIBK
3   103L    A   HJGDSDDLKEIEWUSKDSK OLKDSJDJFYEUKIBK
4   103M    A   HJGDSDDLKEIEWUSKDSK OLKDSJDJFYEUKIBK
```

Comment: Thanks! This is near.
Below I've posted table I exactly need.

Comment: My first post was wrong, so I corrected it. The data is created appropriately. (This is not the data that was just posted.)

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly wat I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask for this code with comments so I could learn on this example?

Comment: I added a comment. Did you understand the content of the comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
    PDB_ID  Chain          Sequence                  Secstr
0   101M     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHH  HHHHGGHH HHHH
1   102L     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA    HHHH  HHHHHHHGGHH   HH
2   102M     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA    HHHHHHHHHGGHH HHH     
3   103L     A       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHHH HHHHHH HHGGH 
4   103L     B       MVLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEA       HHHHH HHHHHH HHHHH
```

I need data something like that